# Can D-Bus be configured to persist messages to a durable store?

Tags: ipc, messaging, dbus

It's possible to use various implementations [D-Bus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/) to queue messages and defer their delivery until a receiver/subscriber has also connected/received them. The messages are internally queued somewhere (a Unix domain socket in most implementations, I think).

Is there a way to configure D-Bus such that those queued messages persist across a restart of the D-Bus daemon or across a reboot of the host running the bus?

For example, if I publish a bunch of messages and consumers are still chewing through the message queue when the dbus daemon is shut down or the system is restarted, the messages should persist and be able to be re-delivered when the system comes back up.

If there is additional setup/manual reconfiguration of dbus needed to get hooked back up to a persistent message store, that is fine.

If this is possible (and it may not be), I'd prefer to avoid having additional services running hooked up to dbus to do the persistence. If that's the only way to get message persistence, that's fine, but I'd like to keep the setup as simple as possible if I can.